# Signlessness seems to be contradictory to Buddhism

Tags: terminology

Signlessness is a concept that I was taught about Buddhism in a college course on Buddhism. It was defined as "not taking omens to have meaning, whether the omen was good or bad does not matter."

But in the same course I learned the mystical means by which the new Dali Lama was found. They see letters in sky telling them to go to Ando Province.

Maybe this is right-mindfulness(?): we see things as they truly are in reality and do impose logic onto things were there should not be. Like if I see my lucky number right as I have that really good feeling when I know I am making the right decision. Must I regard seeing my lucky number as just a coincidence and not a sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, in Mahayana, signlessness (`animitta`) has nothing to do with omens. To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bh%C5%ABmi_(Buddhism)),

> Signlessness refers to the fact that phenomena seem to possess their
>   apparent qualities by way of their own nature, but when one examines
>   this appearance one realizes that all qualities are merely mentally
>   imputed and not a part of the nature of the objects they appear to
>   characterize.

Basically, signlessness means not getting caught into traps of abstractions. This is based on clear understanding that real world is infinitely more nuanced and multifaceted than any concept, however precise, can ever dream to capture. There is an infinite number of alternative ways of describing the world -- each valid in its own context.

The notion of signlessness is related to `aniketa-cārī` (usually translated as "wandering without a home" but having a broader meaning in Mahayana) -- the practice of "non-abiding", or not settling on any single conceptual, metaphysical, or philosophical base.

Answer (score 0):

The [Kalama Sutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalama_Sutta) deals with some of the logical aspects mentioned in your question. Much of your experience is governed by [cause and effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prat%C4%ABtyasamutp%C4%81da). Omens may have some significance but such significance is highly speculative unless you know the laws of cause and effect to its entirety, thus it is best to concentrate on more pragmatic things like understanding the laws of cause and effect, which intern might give you real insight into the nature of omens.

To understand the the laws of cause and effect you have to practice to [Nobel 8 Fold Path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Eightfold_Path) organised according to the [3 fold training](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefold_Training). One aspect of this is Right Mindfulness which also appears in many places in the [factors of enlightenment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bodhipakkhiy%C4%81dhamm%C4%81).

As a 1st step you can do a course in meditation throug https://www.dhamma.org/ or any other [Vippasana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vipassan%C4%81) Meditation Centure.

Answer (score 0):

http://archives.dailynews.lk/2011/01/27/fea25.asp

I found some information of this matter as well.

"For bhikkhus, reading marks on the limbs (palmistry); reading omens and signs, interpreting celestial events, interpreting dreams, reading marks on the body (e.g. phenology), offering fire oblations (yaga), offering blood-sacrifices, practising astrology etc are wrong livelihood. Path to Nibbana and the path to gains are different."